# how to extract the url path from my url link in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl

I have a URL link like "http://mobile/testing.php?action=2, when i have this link on my IE browser, it will redirect the link to "http://mobile/myimage.jpeg". It directed to my database server folder name, where my the file I stored called myimage.jpeg.

I am wondering I how can I can put "http://mobile/testing.php?action=2", establish the NSURL connection and let the Xcode learn this path "http://mobile/myimage.jpeg" so that I can extract the image.jpeg and store it into a list where this list can reflect all the files I had in my database.

Anyone can help? would there be any NSURL reference I can use? I did checkup on the pathomponent, but I don know how can I implement it.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. You are referring to Objective-C as language and Cocoa-Touch as API. Please change your question accordingly.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know where it actually gets redirected to, then you'll need to use an asynchronous `NSURLConnection` and implement the [`-[<NSURLConnectionDelegate> connection:didReceiveResponse:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJFIJBC) delegate method.

The [`NSURLResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLResponse) object passed to that method will actually be an [`NSHTTPURLResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSHTTPURLResponse), which means you can:

1. Ask it for its [`-statusCode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001694-CJBECBFB).  If the code is a [redirection code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection), then you know your original request was redirected, at which point you can...
2. Ask it for its [`-URL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001831-CJBBAJDD).  This is the `NSURL` to which your original request was redirected.  From here, you can get its [`-lastPathComponent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW22) to extract the "myimage.jpeg" bit.

---

If I've totally misunderstood your question, then you can probably just extract the `-path` from your starting URL and get the `-lastPathComponent` from that.

Comment: Yes. I got it. I simply used:

NSHTTPRespone *myresponse; 
NSLog(@"%@", myresponse.URL.lastlastcomponent);

and I am able to achieve my lastPathComponent name. Thank for the help. :) cheer